Bounding $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) \sin (\pi s)$ to prove Euler reflection formula
I was reading lecture notes of the course $18.785$ offered by MIT. The author makes an error and write $|\sin(\pi s)|$ as $\frac{1}{2}|e^{is} - e^{i\overline{s}}|$ as can be seen in the picture. Could we show using some other method that $|\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) \sin(\pi s)| = O(e^{i \text{Im}(s)})$ in the strip $0 \leq \text{Re}(s) \leq 1$ as $\text{Im}(s) \to \infty$. Since we can then use Lemma $17.14$ in the picture to conclude that $\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1-s) \sin(\pi s)$ is constant.


Here is a proof:
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/the-extended-riemann-hypothesis-and-ramanujans-sum/#Supplementary-Theorem-of-the-Gamma-Function-Euler-1749

When your question is dependent on a picture, it might be helpful to actually include said picture in the post.

Can't believe I forgot to upload it. My bad.
